# Mark a state if it is part of another register

Tags: grovers-algorithm, superposition, oracles

I am wondering something, especially about Grover algorithm: imagine I have a quantum register $a$ and a quantum register $b$ of equal length.

Then, suppose I apply some algorithms on $a$ s.t. it is now a uniform superposition of states that, when classicaly translated to binary, are non-zero multiples of 3 (e.g. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|011>+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|110>$ if $a$ had 3 qubits). Similary, I want only non-zero multiples of 2 in $b$ (e.g. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|010>+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|100>+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|110>$ if $b$ had 3 qubits). Something close to that can be obtained with Grover algorithm.

Here comes the question : is there a way to increase the probability of observing values of $a$ such that they also appear in $b$ ? (e.g. we would want to measure $|110>$)

Comment: If you're using Grover's search to find only marked states (e.g. where you mark based on the value being a multiple of 3, say), why can't you mark based on two or more properties, somputing a net outcome using "AND"? (which, in this case, would of course equate to checking divisibility by 6).

Comment: @DaftWullie good question. In fact, this example is quite trivial, but the "real" application I have in mind is more complex and I was thinking it wasn't necessary to fully describe it. In the real application, I want to find two different numbers satisfying something in common, I think a closer example would be the hash collision : to find two numers having the same hashvalue given a hash function. The plan is then to put a in superposition, same for b, then compute h(a) and mark b states where h(b) equals at least one h(a)

Comment: I think you should just think of a $2n$-qubit register which you prepare in a uniform superposition $\sum_{x,y}|x,y\rangle$ and your marking function for Grover's should be based on some function $f(x,y)$ such as "$h(x)=h(y)$?".